# polymorphic constructor for type-level list

Tags: haskell

I have a type-level list L, and am trying to write a polymorphic mkL, that can be used as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, PolyKinds, DataKinds, TypeFamilies,
  UndecidableInstances, AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeSynonymInstances,
  FlexibleInstances, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

data T = Foo | Bar
    deriving (Show, Eq)

data L (ts :: [T]) = L [T]
    deriving (Show, Eq)

demo1 :: L '[Foo]
demo1 = mkL

demo2 :: L '[Foo, Bar]
demo2 = mkL
```

I have demo1 working easily enough, but the recursive case is defeating me for some reason.

```
class MkL p where
    mkL :: p
instance MkL (L '[]) where
    mkL = L []
instance MkL (L '[Foo]) where
    mkL = L [Foo]
instance MkL (L '[Bar]) where
    mkL = L [Bar]
instance MkL (L (l1 ': l2 ': ls)) where
    mkL =
        let (L [l1]) = undefined -- FIXME
            (L [l2]) = undefined
            (L rest) = undefined
        in L (l1 : l2 : rest)
```

If I replace the FIXME with mkL, I get:

```
No instance for (MkL (L t0)) arising from a use of ‘mkL’
The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance MkL (L (l1 : l2 : ls)) -- Defined at Target.hs:19:10
  instance MkL (L '['Bar]) -- Defined at Target.hs:17:10
  instance MkL (L '['Foo]) -- Defined at Target.hs:15:10
  ...plus one other
In the expression: mkL
In a pattern binding: (L [l1]) = mkL
```

So, is there any way to implement this?

Comment: Though you're defining mkL recursively and you've defined your base cases, your last instance is missing a crucial element that makes it, currently, completely non-recursive! How might you use Haskell to introduce the appropriate MkL constraints and thus let the recursion kick in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must write recursive functions on lists according to the recursive structure of lists. A list is either `[]` or `_ : _`:

```
instance MkL (L '[]) where 
  mkL = L [] 

instance MkL (L xs) => MkL (L ('Foo ': xs)) where 
  mkL = let L xs = mkL :: L xs in L (Foo : xs)

instance MkL (L xs) => MkL (L ('Bar ': xs)) where 
  mkL = let L xs = mkL :: L xs in L (Bar : xs)
```

But it should be noted that your `L` type is probably not what you want. As far as the compiler is concerned, there is no relation between the value level `[T]` and the type level `[T]`. This is perfectly valid:

```
instance MkL (L xs) where 
  mkL = L []
```

To store a value level representation of the type level list, you must do something like

```
data family SingT (x :: k) 

data instance SingT (x :: [k]) where 
  Nil :: SingT '[] 
  Cons :: SingT x -> SingT xs -> SingT (x ': xs) 

data instance SingT (x :: T) where 
  SFoo :: SingT 'Foo 
  SBar :: SingT 'Bar 

class Sing a where 
  sing :: SingT a 

instance Sing 'Foo where sing = SFoo 
instance Sing 'Bar where sing = SBar
instance (Sing x, Sing xs) => Sing (x ': xs) where sing = Cons sing sing  
instance Sing '[] where sing = Nil
```

Then you have `sing :: SingT '[ 'Foo, 'Bar ]`, etc, and this type is inhabited only by `Cons SFoo (Cons SBar Nil)`. There are packages, eg [singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons), which partially automate the process of defining such a `SingT` type.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider three cases: the empty list, the lists with `Foo` at the head, and the lists with `Bar` at the head. Translated to instances:

```
instance MkL (L '[]) where
  mkL = L []

instance MkL (L ts) => MkL (L (Foo ': ts)) where
  mkL = case mkL :: L ts of L ts -> L (Foo : ts)

instance MkL (L ts) => MkL (L (Bar ': ts)) where
  mkL = case mkL :: L ts of L ts -> L (Bar : ts)
```

There's no need here to consider lists  of `n + 2` length for some `n`, since I assume we'd like to have instances for all `ts :: [T]`, and the empty and `(:)` constructors cover them all.

---

On a different note, there's an [existing library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) covering this use case, and it's safer and generally more powerful. It lets us generate (via Template Haskell, but one could also write it by hand) value-level representatives of type-level data (called "singletons") or type-level representatives of value-level functions, and gives us plenty of tools for working with them.

For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-} -- on the top of the others

import Data.Singletons.TH

$(singletons [d| data T = Foo | Bar |])
```

This defines (among other things) the `SFoo :: Sing Foo` and `SBar :: Sing Bar` constructors, where `Sing` is a data family and `Sing x` contains exactly the value-level representative of some `x` type. For each `Sing x` there is just a single value (that's why it's a singleton), therefore it's possible to unambiguously determine a type from its singleton.

```
sFoo :: Sing Foo
sFoo = SFoo

sBar :: Sing Bar
sBar = SBar

demo1 :: Sing '[Foo]
demo1 = sing

demo2 :: Sing '[Foo, Bar]
demo2 = sing
```

`sing` is similar to your `Mk` class, except it works across many different kinds.

Here, `demo1` is equal to `SCons SFoo SNil`, where `SCons` and `SNil` are the singleton constructors representing type-level lists. If we don't want to work with singletons though, we can erase the type indices and work with plain old data:

```
demo1' :: [T]
demo1' = fromSing demo1
```

Now `demo1` equals `[Foo]`, so `fromSing` converts the `S`-prefixed singletons back to the simple representations.

The biggest benefit of working with singletons is that they mirror the types perfectly, so it's not possibly to "cheat"; in contrast, we could have arbitrary values of `L ts` at runtime that doesn't conform to the phantom type index. In a nutshell, in `L ts` the index is just a phantom type, but in `Sing ts`, the index is precisely reflected in the constructors.

Comment: It's also some pretty scary-looking Template Haskell. :-/